# Contar registros en mysql con select count

Tags: java, mysql

Hola tengo la siguiente consulta sql y funciona para mi primer propósito.

```
SELECT unidad, mantenimiento, SUM(kmreco) as kmr 
FROM mytabla GROUP BY unidad 
WHERE HAVING SUM(kmreco)  >=4000
```

Lo que hace es traerme organizado por unidad el total de kilómetros recorridos o sea la suma final.

Bien ahora necesito una consulta que cuente la cantidad de filas que cumplen con la condición de >=4000. He tratado de usar COUNT() pero no me ha funcionando. 
Solo necesito devolver el numero de filas que cumplen con esa condición.

Comment: Sería: **`SELECT COUNT(*) total FROM mytabla GROUP BY unidad WHERE HAVING SUM(kmreco) >=4000`**

Comment: Tu consulta funciona pero no trae un solo valor sino todas las filas que se usan oara sumar el kmreco

Comment: Ok, o sea ¿ya no quieres agrupar por `unidad`?, entonces quita el `GROUP BY`, haciendo esto: **`SELECT COUNT(*) total FROM mytabla WHERE HAVING SUM(kmreco) >=4000`** si no es eso entonces acláranos qué resultados esperas y qué filtros hay que aplicar en sí.

Comment: Ok explico los resultados que deseo. En mytabla tengo campos de esta manera: id, unidad, mantenimiento, kmreco. Necesito notificarle al usuario que una unidad ya sobrepasó los 4000 kilómetros. Entonces lo que me plante es sumar "SUM(kmreco)" en la consulta y despues contar la cantidad de filas que al contar den un resultado de 4000 o mas. Filas que den el resultado de 3999 hacia abajo no deben mostrarce.

Comment: Bueno sí, pero no dices bajo qué criterio se debe sumar. Supongamos que es de un determinado `id`, entonces pones: `SELECT COUNT(*) total FROM mytabla GROUP BY id WHERE HAVING SUM(kmreco) >=4000 AND id=2`.  Ahí agrupas por `id` y además filtras para indicar que quieres los datos del id 2.  si quitas el `AND id=2` te traerá varias filas, pero agrupadas por cada `id`.

Comment: Bueno esa consulta se ejecuta al inciar la interfaz, no le paso parametros solo ejecuto el select ademas como dices del criterio pues es por unidad que es igual a la matricula

Comment: Es que no entiendo, ¿los registros de quién quieres contar, de todas las filas o de las filas de alguien o algo en específico? Si el criterio es `unidad` cambias `id` por `unidad` tanto en el `GROUP BY` como en el `WHERE`. En cuanto a que se ejecuta al iniciar la interfaz no entiendo lo que quieres decir. Supongo que en ese contexto hay algún dato para establecer el filtro.

Comment: Contar todos los registros de todas las unidades que la suma de la columna kmreco de mayo o igual a 4000. Si no es asi no debe ser contada. No se si estoy planteando mal o no se puede realizar esto en mysql.

Comment: ¿Acaso esta consulta no hace eso que dices: `SELECT COUNT(*) total FROM mytabla WHERE HAVING SUM(kmreco) >=4000`?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89532/discussion-between-riddick-and-a-cedano).